# on a divergent integral

Tags: complex-analysis

we have the integral : 
$$\lim_{T\to \infty }\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT}\frac{(s-1)^{n}}{s}ds$$

which diverges for every value of n except $n=0$
if we perform the change of variables :

$$s\rightarrow \frac{1}{s}$$

then : 
$$\lim_{T\to \infty }\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT}\frac{(s-1)^{n}}{s}ds=\int_{-i}^{i}\frac{(1-s)^{n}}{s^{n+1}}ds$$

which converges . am i missing something here , or is this correct !?

Comment: The change of variable also changes the limits ...

Comment: I have computed the following limits of integration $$\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT}\frac{(s-1)^{n}}{s}ds=\int_{\frac{2-iT}{4+T^{2}}}^{\frac{
2+iT}{4+T^{2}}}\frac{\left( 1-w\right) ^{n}}{w^{n+1}}\,dw.$$

Comment: ... So it seems you claim that

$$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty }\int_{\frac{2-iT}{4+T^{2}}}^{\frac{2+iT}{4+T^{2}}
}\frac{\left( 1-w\right) ^{n}}{w^{n+1}}\,dw=\int_{-i}^{i}\frac{\left(
1-w\right) ^{n}}{w^{n+1}}\,dw.$$

Comment: ok .. i see where i went wrong .. thanks @AméricoTavares

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal All this is not that relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the original path of integration is a line between the endpoints. If so, the limiting path gets mapped to the circle below which loops from the origin, through $\frac12$, and back to the origin again. Note that
$$
-\int_C\frac{(1-s)^{n}}{s^{n+1}}ds
$$
diverges near the origin.

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: complex paths]

Answer (score 3):

For integrals in the complex plane you must specify not just the endpoints, but the path involved.  I'm assuming your original integral is
$$ J_T = \int_{\Gamma_T} \frac{(s-1)^n}{s} \ ds $$
where $\Gamma_T$ is the straight line from $2-iT$ to $2+iT$. The substitution $z=1/s$ transforms this to $\int_{C_T} \frac{(1-z)^n}{z^{n+1}}\ dz$
where $C_T$ goes from $1/(2+iT)$ to $1/(2-iT)$ on the arc not containing $0$ of a circle  of radius $1/4$ centred at $1/4$.  There's no reason to expect convergence.